# Human Model, do we have one in GAZEBO?

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all

Is there a HUMAN model in GAZEBO?

I don't need it to be move-able, just a human model. Either in URDF or SDF is fine.

Thank you

Candy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9235/human-model,-do-we-have-one-in-gazebo?/) by [randy_wales](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1333/randy_wales/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-08-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2015-08-28**:
there's one in https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/348b3de008a00cc7b73ad95ad1b8ce00c9d22024/worlds/actor.world?at=default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There's no human model in the database yet. You can always use your own model if you have the COLLADA or STL meshes.

Also note that there's currently a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/pull-requests/164/add-models-of-a-person/diff) to gazebo_models to add couple of human models without joints to the database.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1